# How to rotate UV mapping on skysphere (equirectangular)?

Tags: materials, uv, node-editor, skybox

Alright so I've followed a basic tutorial to create a skysphere mapped to an equirectangular environment texture. This is fine, however the mapping is at a slight tilt (pictured below), which is getting in the way of making the sphere -> skydome.

[image]

I've tried adjusting the tilt with basic mapping nodes, but this results in the texture being warped --

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the tutorial?  Another thing, I used a UV Sphere and using the UV output of the texture coordinate map, I was able to make this skysphere thingy with no issues. Maybe try doing what I said. Coz when I plugged the generated output into the vector input of the image texture, I was getting something that was nowhere near what you have created. Viz why I am asking for the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot map it to an "equirectangular environment texture" when you are using an *Image Texture* node, which you can clearly see because the projection method is set to *Flat*:

[image: image texture]

Instead use the correct *Environment Texture* node by adding it with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Add* > *Texture* > *Environment Texture*. The projection method should by default be set to *Equirectangular*, the only other option is *Mirror Ball* (there is no *Flat* option):

[image: environment texture]

Either this is a strange tutorial if they are using an *Image Texture* node or you have to make sure you pay attention to all steps to get everything correct. Especially for beginners I understand that it is often not easy to realize the exact differences in Blender, so probably rewatching tutorials might help.

For the *Texture Coordinate* and *Mapping* nodes: I have no idea how they have set it up in the tutorial, but with a correct *Environment Texture* node on a sphere I would do one of the following things: in any case first of all set the *Mapping* node *Type* to *Point* instead of *Vector*.

Then from the *Texture Coordinate* node either use the *Generated* output or the *Object* output. With *Object* you do not have to do anything (you would not even need the *Mapping* node), for *Generated* set all three XYZ values for *Location* to -0.5, although note that if you want to change the *Rotation* of the image it will get warped too when using the *Generated* output, use *Object* instead.

[image: mapping]